# Reset password email not translating in Laravel 8.53

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to translate password reset emails into Laravel. (for frontend I use Vue.js)

in `config/app.php` I have set the desired language

```
 'locale' => 'sl',
 'fallback_locale' => 'sl',
```

than I downloaded translations from https://github.com/Laravel-Lang/lang and put folder "locales\sl" in downloaded repository into `resources\lang\sl` in my project.

I use custom email notification `app\Notifications\ResetPasswordNotification.php` where I added:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
```

and for translating I used:

```
->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
```

This translation is stored in `resources\lang\sl\sl.json`

Now when the email is sent I get no errors but the email is still in English, but let's say API responses are in the desired language.

```
{"status": "We have emailed your password reset link!"}
```

^^ this status gets translated into the language specified in `config/app.php`

I run these two lines, but no effect...

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this.
I moved sl.json form `resources\lang\sl\sl.json` into `resources\lang\sl.json` :)

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a few hours of searching :)